# Should I include sold out items?

Tags: design-patterns, marketing, dark-patterns

I'm working on an e-commerce site that doesn't have many products (actually there are only 5). These products are high quality and quite expensive.

Now the most desirable product (the 2nd most expensive, just in case it makes a difference) is sold out. This product is the most desirable because there are a number of variables that have been carefully crafted to make this product the best seller. Now the product is sold out and won't be sold again because of reasons that don't matter.

So the question is: **should we leave it as it's now (with a huge sold-out badge and no possible interaction), or should we remove it?** Normally, I'd remove it, but then I'd have to put extra work on the developers, since the website and app use a custom CMS and have their own data-driven implementation logic. Also, and this is my main concern, I think mentioning that we had it, even if we no longer have it, would give us some authority and make the other products more desirable.

I know we're not fooling anyone as long as we don't advertise it, but people who come from search engines may come because of the description of this product, which puts us on the verge of a dark pattern **(Artificial Scarcity)**.

In short, what would be the right solution to this problem? Remove it? Keep it? Keep it, but...?

Comment: If you remove it, will your support team get a lot of calls asking where it went?

Comment: @Izquierdo to be honest, no idea and didn't think about it, so that's another concern, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Personally, if the product is not going to be restocked I would say deleting it would be the better option. A sold out product makes me think that it will eventually be restocked at some point, so I would feel tricked if I learned later that it will not be restocked. Maybe instead of "sold out/out of stock", you can use "unavailable" or "No longer available" if you wish to gain the authority from previously having this product. There can be exceptions, however, if the item is something that is low quantity/rare. For example, baseball cards might only have 1 of a rare card in stock, but showing the "sold out" of a rare card can give the website credibility, prompting the user to browse for more cards. I think it depends on whether the products on this website are rare (like baseball cards) or are fairly common (like a clothes store).

Comment: Despite the huge differences, the baseball cards are a huge analogy. The product is a high-tech proprietary and patented development in the health industry. It's discontinued because there´s an even better version in the making so it makes no sense to add more stock of the old version, but the credibility of having done this product is really important in its industry. Kind of "from the creators of..."

Comment: In that case, I think making sure that the wording makes it clear that the item is no longer available, not just out of stock, is the main factor. Maybe to reduce the artificial scarcity worries, you can add a "coming soon" of your better version product with a similar description so users coming from search engines/description of the product can see a product that they can check back for later. Possibly include a "notify me when in stock" option as well.